# Proof for Language: L1 ∪ L2 ⊆ L1L2

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I have a question for my thesis research, but I am not able to find proof of this. Does anyone have any idea on what should be approach be in order to prove this?

Question: `Prove that L1 ∪ L2 ⊆ L1L2, if λ ∈ L1 ∩ L2`

Comment: It is the case if L1 and L2 both contain the empty string, and in that case it is obvious. I wouldn’t even bother writing down a proof. That’s why you can’t find it.

Comment: (Where something is too obvious, prove by contradiction.)

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving elementary tasks for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Unless both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are empty, it seems also the opposite implication holds: If $L_1\cup L_2\subseteq L_1L_2$ then $\lambda \in L_1\cap L_2$.

Comment: You can write it in the thesis without a proof..., but if you insist, you can write something like: It is easy to see that "your claim". Indeed, concatenating $\lambda$ to any word from the left or the right, results in the same word.

Comment: @HendrikJan I would want to see a proof for that. Definitely not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $L_1 \cup L_2 \subseteq L_1L_2$

you prove that $\forall x. (x\in L_1 \cup L_2) \rightarrow(x\in L_1L_2)$

To prove *that*, you prove that

$\forall x. (x\in L_1) \rightarrow(x\in L_1L_2)$

and

$\forall x. (x\in L_2) \rightarrow(x\in L_1L_2)$

Can you see where to go from there?